# If a woman exposes awrah to another woman, what is invalid?

Tags: women, awrah

If a woman uncovers or exposes her awrah (private part) to another woman because of a medical procedure (example laser hair removal in the private parts), is it sinful? What does this act invalidate? Does it make prayer invalid? For how long does it make prayer invalid? Does it invalidate wudu? What else should I know?

I have to get laser hair removal twice a year in the private part (and rest of my body) because when the hair grows it's thick.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assalamualykum,
Exposing the awrah for both male and females to anyone is totally haram, unless there is a valid reason like the above statement of needing medical treatment. It is much better to do this with a person of the same sex like you have. Since the act is for a medical reason, this is totally halal and will not invalidate anything.

Also, the person should be of the same sex, not gender as in this day and age, according to Western laws, people can change their gender so they may not be the same sex as you. Before you accept the treatment, make sure to check if the person you are exposing your awrah to is of **the same biological sex**, not just gender.